# how to make this beautiful routing switching effects via react.js or react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image]

video is here:
https://www.pinterest.com/pin/576531189812450991/

very beautiful routing switching effects, but can't find the react.js solution.

try to use `react-transition-group`, but can't do this.

any ideas? thank you very much！

Comment: Have a look at [react-native-shared-element](https://github.com/IjzerenHein/react-native-shared-element)

Comment: very nice @Pim ！ 
best to find out  react.js solution